# Do I need Celery (distributed task queue) in this use case?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have two web servers, one is asynchronous and the other is synchronous. The asynchronous server  deals with real-time interactions with clients on a page, while the synchronous one serves up the static content of the page, among other common tasks of a synchronous web server (such as authentication, static pages, etc).

I would like to connect the two servers so that the interaction data gathered on the asynchronous server can be sent to the synchronous server which will then save the data to a database. To implement this, I will use a RabbitMQ so that each message containing the data is sent from the asynchronous server to the synchronous one. Upon receiving these messages, the synchronous server process them one by one.

I wonder if I may also need to use Celery to better the performance in this two-server case? What if I need to scale this setup to multiple asynchronous as well as multiple synchronous servers? How should I utilize Celery then?

Answer (score 0):

You understand everything right, but can you just implement saving stuff on celery Daemon. Also you can see other easier solution. You can just call GET-POST requests with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ from your async server to sync server. So. its easy cinvertation from async to sync. I think its better for you now.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I choose a message queue over GET-POST requests because it is more robust for the communication between two servers, especially considering the use of rabbitmq. Could you elaborate a bit more on how should I use celery in addition to rabbitmq here, and why?